# cakephp redirection error after login return HTTP/1.1 302 in the logs

Tags: cakephp, redirect, http-status-code-302

I have implemented cakephp **redirect()** function on successfull login into my application .

But the redirection is not working for some reasons and it is instead getting redirected to the same url , while in the APACHE logs , I can see HTTP 302 response for that redirected URL .

My code is something as under :

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']) && $_REQUEST['submit']=='Log In')
    {
        /*Entire validation logic goes here*/
        if(isset($famUserInfo['user_type']) && $famUserInfo['user_type'] == USER_TYPE_ADVERTISER)
        {
            $redirectTo = !empty($returnto)?$returnto:'/homepageadv?login=1';
        }
        else if(isset($adminUserInfo['user_type']) && $adminUserInfo['user_type'] == USER_TYPE_ADMIN)
        {
                           /* My control flow comes till here successfully */
            $this->redirect("/opstool/zoneprobabilityindex");
            die;
        }
        else
        {
            $redirectTo = !empty($returnto)?$returnto:'/homepage?login=1';
        }

        $this->redirect($redirectTo);
        die;
    }
```

When I check in the APACHE logs , I noticed like these :

```
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Oct/2011:19:24:34 +0530] "POST /login?returnto= HTTP/1.1" 302 5
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Oct/2011:19:24:34 +0530] "GET /opstool/zoneprobabilityindex HTTP/1.1" 302 12
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Oct/2011:19:24:34 +0530] "GET /login?returnto= HTTP/1.1" 200 6057
```

**http://localhost:9001/login?returnto=** is my login page url and this where it's returning to.

My .htaccess contents is inside /app folder and is as follows :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Please help. I am struck on this.

Comment: Any luck? I am almost in the same boat!

Comment: @HonorGod...Instead of dwelving deeper into it , I copied my entire code in a different folder and changed the port number and previous entry in Apache httpd.conf . It worked for me.

Comment: @debaShish ??? :| .. Interesting comment. I think I am having the same issue as well, not sure what exactly is causing this, and it only happens in production.